# Prove that if $A$ is a countable set then the class $^{\in \omega}A=\{f:\text{ for some } n\in \omega, f\in\ ^{n}A\}$ is a set

Tags: set-theory

In section 5.2 of "Daniel W. Cunningham. *Set Theory: A First Course*.", the author wrote:

> By applying Theorem 2.1.3 (see below), one can show that the following class is a set: $$^{\in \omega}A=\{f:\text{for some } n\in \omega, f \text{ is a function from }n \text{ to }A\}.$$

Where $A$ is a countable set and $\omega$ is the set of natural numbers, $^{B}A$ denotes a set of functions from $B$ to $A$.

Theorem 2.1.3:

> Let $\varphi$ be a formula. Suppose that there is a set $S$ such that for all $x$, if $\varphi$, then $x\in S$. Then there is a unique set $\mathcal{D}$ such that for all $x$, $x\in \mathcal{D}$ if and only if $\varphi(x)$.

I'm having trouble applying the theorem. The reason is because $n$ is any element in $\omega$ so there are multiple sets $^{n}A$ contain $f$ but there's only one set $S$ mentioned in the theorem. So how can I construct the formula for $\varphi(f)$ now?

I can use the *Infinity Axiom* coupled with some other theorems (without using the theorem above) to get the result but that's way too long and not the way author hinting at.

Comment: @user10354138, that's somewhat more complicated to me while the proof should be simple. I've added some details to the question so pls look at it again.

Comment: You can take $S=P(\omega\times A)$. (I assume there’s a typo and it should say “$f$ is a function $n\to A$.” Also somewhat baffled at the relevance of $A$ being countable here, as well as the relevance of the definition of $^B A$, which doesn’t appear. The notation $^{\in \omega} A$ would be more familiar / readable as $^{<\omega} A$.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen you're right, it's my typo not the book's. I've corrected it. And your suggestion indeed works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @spaceisdarkgreen 's suggestion:

From Infinity Axiom, $\omega$ is a set so $\omega\times A$ is a set and so $\mathcal{P}(\omega\times A)$ is also a set. Therefore:

$$
\begin{align}
f:n\rightarrow A\text{ for some }n\in \omega &\Longrightarrow f\subseteq n\times A\\
&\Longrightarrow f\subseteq \omega\times A&(n\times A \subseteq \omega\times A\text{ for }n\in \omega)\\
&\Longrightarrow  f\in \mathcal{P}(\omega\times A).
\end{align}
$$

Let $S=\mathcal{P}(\omega\times A)$ and $\varphi(f)=(\exists n\in\omega)(f\in\ ^{n}A)$ and so we can apply Theorem 2.1.3 for $^{\in\omega}A=\{f: f\text{ is a function from }n\text{ to }A\text{, for some }n\in A\}$.